# Show that pushforward measure is inner regular

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X, Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces, $\tau:Y \to X$ continuous and $\mu^\tau:=\mu \circ \tau^{-1}$ the pushforward measure of the measure $\mu$ which is a inner regular measure. Show that $\mu^\tau$ is inner regular as well.

We have to show that $\mu^\tau(A)=\sup\{\mu^\tau(K):K\subseteq A, K\ \mathrm{compact}\}, \forall \ \mathrm{measurable\ } A \subseteq X$

I tried:
$\mu^\tau(A)=\mu(\tau^{-1}(A))=\sup\{\mu(K):K \subseteq \tau^{-1}(A), K\ \mathrm{compact}\}=\sup\{\mu(\tau^{-1}(K)):K \subseteq (A), K\ \mathrm{compact}\}=\sup\{\mu^\tau(K):K \subseteq (A), K\ \mathrm{compact}\}$

> Where do we use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces?

It should also work for non compact Hausdorff spaces. But where do we use the hausdorff property?

Comment: In your try, how do you justify the third equals sign?

Comment: @DanielFischer I simply thought it would work like this to be honest. How would the correct proof look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use (parts of) the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces in the justification of the third equals sign of your try. The other equals signs are immediately justified from the definition of $\mu^{\tau}$ and the assumption of inner regularity of $\mu$.

Let's go from right to left, and start with
$$\sup \: \{\mu(\tau^{-1}(K)) : K \subseteq A, K \text{ compact}\}\,.$$
Since $X$ is a Hausdorff space, we know that all the $K$ considered there are *closed* subsets of $X$. Hence $\tau^{-1}(K)$ is closed in $Y$ for all these $K$. Since $Y$ is compact, it follows that $\tau^{-1}(K)$ is compact. And clearly $\tau^{-1}(K) \subset \tau^{-1}(A)$, thus the family $\mathscr{F} = \{\tau^{-1}(K) : K \subseteq A, K \text{ compact}\}$ is a subfamily of the family of compact subsets of $\tau^{-1}(A)$, which shows
$$\sup \: \{\mu(\tau^{-1}(K)) : K \subseteq A, K \text{ compact}\} \leqslant \sup\: \{ \mu(L) : L \subseteq \tau^{-1}(A), L \text{ compact}\}\,.$$
For this inference we need that compact subsets of $X$ are closed (which is a weaker assumption than Hausdorffness, but $X$ being Hausdorff is a less exotic assumption, satisfied in most cases one may be interested in), and that $Y$ is compact.

For the other inequality, it suffices to see that every compact $L \subseteq \tau^{-1}(A)$ is contained in some member of $\mathscr{F}$. This is straightforward, since $L \subseteq \tau^{-1}(\tau(L))$, and $\tau(L)$ is compact by the continuity of $\tau$ — hence closed by the assumption on $X$ — and therefore $\tau^{-1}(\tau(L))$ is a member of $\mathscr{F}$ containing $L$. Thus
$$\mu(L) \leqslant \sup \: \{\mu(\tau^{-1}(K)) : K \subseteq A, K \text{ compact}\}$$
for every compact $L \subseteq \tau^{-1}(A)$, and the third equals sign is established.

Thus we used the compactness of the domain and (a consequence of) the Hausdorffness of the codomain for the proof. We see that the assumptions are stronger than needed, but not entirely superfluous.